# Oracle SQL Database Table Column Importance

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I understand which columns are important in a table in oracle SQL Database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om2PQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important? Probably the ones that aren't `NULL`. The rest? Who knows ... tables contain data related to *something*. If columns don't have description, then ask the author what they represent and which ones of these are "important", and which are not.